# Magento 2 MTF: Several test methods in one Class

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, testing

I used Magento 1 testing framework. It was outdated because of using Selenium RC instead of Webdriver, but it had one very useful feature - you could place as many test methods in class (TestCase) as you wished.

In Magento 2 I see that structure is the following that one TestCase class contains only 1 test method.

Is there any posibility to put several test methods in one class?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you want to achieve, but you can several variations for the same TestCase, but they'll be acting more like Data Providers. Still, functional tests can be quite complex, so if you need something more enhanced than just data providers, I would strongly suggest you to create separated test cases.

You can also have a look into [fooman/sameorderinvoicenumber-m2](https://github.com/fooman/sameorderinvoicenumber-m2/blob/develop/tests/functional/tests/app/Fooman/SameOrderInvoiceNumber/Test/TestCase/InvoiceTest.xml)'s functional tests to see how we used it there. It might not be the best approach, but it's something to start with.